# how to align image and text

Tags: html, css

I have table defined in style like this:

```
  <style>
table.box-left, table.box-left td, table.box-left th {
            border: 1px solid #005a8c;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            width: 320px;
            box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #888888;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
        }
            table.box-left thead tr .lightgreen {
                height: 20px;
                background-color: #8DB135;
            }
 </style>
```

In the table cell I have an image and a paragraph of text,  for some reason text doesn't wrap around the image.  Can someone help?????

```
<table class="box-left">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th class="lightgreen">Test</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tr>
                                <td>

                                     <img src="../images/54.jpg" width="80" height="140" />

                                   Hello, for some reason text doesn't display correctly as it supposed to. Can you help? Thanks so much in advance!!!
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
```

Comment: The box-shadow doesn't work IE. Does anyone know why???? Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: Internet Explorer 9+ supports the box-shadow property: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-shadow.asp

Answer (score 0):

Just add `img { float: left; }` and it should work as expected.

[Check this fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/h0h16bp2/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Modify HTML like this:

```
<table class="box-left">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="lightgreen">Test</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="floated">
                <img src="../images/54.jpg" width="80" height="140" style="position: relative;" />
            </div>
            Hello, for some reason text doesn't display correctly as it supposed to. Can you help? Thanks so much in advance!!!
            Hello, for some reason text doesn't display correctly as it supposed to. Can you help? Thanks so much in advance!!!
            Hello, for some reason text doesn't display correctly as it supposed to. Can you help? Thanks so much in advance!!!
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And add this to CSS:

```
#floated{
    float: left;
}
```

**Check This JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/jhts4hxe/3/**